# Django Max DateTime Aggregation

Tags: python, django, datetime, aggregation

What is the best way of getting the max datetime of related objects of related objects of a Django instance? I need this value as an instance property.

For example, with these models,

```
class Show(Model):
    is_live = BooleanField()
    ...

class Season(Model):
    show = ForeignKeyField(Show, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='seasons')
    is_live = BooleanField()
    ...

class Episode(Model):
    season = ForeignKeyField(Season, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='episodes')
    is_live = BooleanField()
    live_date = DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

How could I get the most recent episode `live_date` of a show instance, including only episodes where the season is_live == True and the episode is_live == True?

I have tried this in the `Show` model:

```
@property
def max_episode_live_date(self)
    return self.seasons.filter(
        is_live=True
     ).aggregate(
        max_=Max(
            'episodes__live_date',
            filter=Q(episodes__is_live=True)
        )
    ).get('max_')
```

but I get this error
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'**

I've tried using [Django SubQuery expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression),

```
@property
def max_episode_live_date(self)
    episodes = Episode.objects.filter(
        is_live=True,
        season=OuterRef('pk')
    ).values('live_date')

    return self.seasons.filter(
        is_live=True
    ).aggregate(
        max_=Max(Subquery(episodes))
    ).get('max_')
```

but then I get **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')**

I believe this is due to some episodes containing null `live_date`, but I'm not sure how to work around. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old topic but here is the solution you are looking for.

This happens when you use MySQL database and as @yanqzhi said the result is `string` when is should be a `datetime`.

To fix this you need to cast the return value like this:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

@property
def max_episode_live_date(self)
    return self.seasons.filter(
        is_live=True
     ).aggregate(
        max_=Cast(
            Max('episodes__live_date', filter=Q(episodes__is_live=True)),
            models.DateTimeField()
        )
    ).get('max_')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@property
def max_episode_live_date(self)
    return self.seasons.filter(
        is_live=True
     ).aggregate(
        max_=Max(
            'episodes__live_date',
            filter=Q(episodes__is_live=True)
        )
    ).get('max_')
```

The SQL

```
"SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN `episode`.`is_live` is true THEN `episode`.`live_date` ELSE NULL END) AS `max_`"
```

will be executed. The result will be a string or None. When a string is converted to DateTime with timezone, the error happens.
I think it may be a bug of Django.